# How can I store any image (size 1mb) in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

How can I store any image (size 1mb) in mongoDB. I know if it's more than 16MB then I should use GRIDFS. But what is the best way if size is around 1-10 MB.

Comment: Here is a helpful link for storing small images in mongodb http://menge.io/2015/03/24/storing-small-images-in-mongodb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the content of the image file into a `byte[]`. The driver will then store it in MongoDB as the [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html) `binary` type. When your application can handle multiple image formats, you should also store the filetype in a different field so you know how to decode it when reading it back into the application.